# Multi-channel recording of sounds in a car using multiple microphones

Tags: audio-recording, multichannel

I'm new to the field. I would like to set up a decent quality (at least 16 bit, 22kHz) multi-channel recording experiment using at least 6 microphones with a budget of ~100-300 bucks to record sounds at various positions in a car (signal leaking between channels to be expected). The mics should be tiny and the wiring flexible and flat. So, my idea is to have 6-12 microphones hooked up to a portable digital recorder, a microcontroller, or a DSP development board capable of handling the data streams (e.g. MCHstreamer kit, https://www.minidsp.com/products/usb-audio-interface/mchstreamer). Note: I'm not trying to build a typical microphone array but I'm interested in simultaneous monitoring of multiple distinct sources.

Does anyone have an idea which setup might be most promising with multiple mics?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Not sure what you mean with setup. Initially, if you are planning to place all mics on a single device, then you are effectively talking about a microphone array, as it will be quite difficult (if not impossible) to monitor different sources with mics that are very close to each other (keep in mind that most MEMS mics are omni).

Comment: Exactly, I'm planning to use a recording setup with microphones that are within an acoustically dense and complex sphere of at least 1 meter diameter with the recorder at the center, every mic in a different acoustic situation.

Comment: Then I believe I cannot help you, since this must be application dependent. As you stated you don't seek to create some kind of array so I guess that post-processing beamforming techniques as well as some kind of sound-field processing (such as Ambisonics or that kind of methods) are out of scope here. Maybe, if you state a somewhat clearer application you will get more answers from experts on this specific application.

Comment: Thanks for your note. I edited the question accordingly.